# Getting error when adding xamarine android assembly dll refrence to .net 472

Tags: .net, xamarin

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1201  Project PreEmptive.Protection.Checks.Runtime.Tamper.XAndroid is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2) / win. Project PreEmptive.Protection.Checks.Runtime.Tamper.XAndroid supports: monoandroid90 (MonoAndroid,Version=v9.0)    dotfuscator_ui  C:\Dotfuscatore\Dotfuscator\Source\dotfuscator_ui\dotfuscator_ui.csproj 1

Comment: Have you check that the project you provided is support .net or not? You could check the link below about more details of .net framework support platforms. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/net-core-1-0-net-framework-xamarin-the-whatand-when-to-use-it/

Comment: target framework for PreEmptive.Protection.Checks.Runtime.Tamper.XAndroid assembly is API Level 29 .i.e v9.0, and I dont know how to add this assembly in .net472 project

Answer (score 0):

The .NET Framework is only supported by **Windows**. If you need to run on a different OS, you cannot use the .NET Framework but you should evaluate and choose between .NET Core or Mono.

If you use the .net standard, sometimes it supported. You could check the link below for details.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-platforms-support?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002999